# How to make HTML time input to show hours only

Tags: html

How can I force HTML time input to render hours only? I do not need to have minutes and seconds in the input.

```html
<label for="appt">Choose a time for your meeting:</label>

<input type="time" id="appt" name="appt"
       min="07:00" max="18:00" value="07:00" required>

<small>Office hours are 9am to 6pm</small>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use step=3600

```html
<label for="appt">Choose a time for your meeting:</label>

<input type="time" id="appt" name="appt"
       min="07:00" max="18:00" value="07:00" step=3600 required>

<small>Office hours are 9am to 6pm</small>
```

more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#step)